# VBA loop through range, by columns first

Tags: vba, excel

Is their any way to loop through a range (ideally a for each cell in X) that can loop columns first? e.g. A1, A2, A3, A4 rather than A1, B1, C1, D1

I tried transposing the range like, but alas this does not work

```
For Each cell In application.transpose(.Range("C3:G100"))
```

I have a feeling I am going to have to use something like

```
for c = 0 to .Range("C3:G100").columns.count
    for r =0 to .range("C3:G100").rows.count
```

Comment: select an answer to say if this can be closed. Keep SO clean, and let us not inflate unanswered question count

Comment: It has not been answered. I know how to do the loops mentioned below but I was not asking that. I was asking if you could do a for each cell in a similar maner, e.g. loop columns first.

Answer (score 2):

```
dim ws as worksheet
set ws = ActiveSheet ' change here as required
For icol = 1 to n '(change here to max)
  For irow = 1 to n '(change here to max)
    'some code here
    ' access cells as ws.cells(irow, icol) 
  nex irow
next icol
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
For Each cell In application.transpose(.Range("C3:G100"))
     
  'Your Code here
     
Next cell
```

with

```
Dim col As Range
For Each col In Range("C3:G100").Columns
   For Each cell In col.Cells
     
     'Your Code here
   
   Next cell
Next col
```

Answer (score 0):

Put it in an array.

```
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim avArray As Variant

avArray = Range("C3:G100").Value

For j = LBound(avArray, 2) To UBound(avArray, 2)
    For i = LBound(avArray, 1) To UBound(avArray, 1)
        avArray(i, j) = CStr(avArray(i, j)) 'do something here, this 
                                            'example just makes the 
                                            'value a string
    Next
Next
```

If you're making changes then just dump the array back to the sheet once you're done

```
Range("C3:G100").Value = avArray
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Below macro will:
(*) in the Active Worksheet:
(1) identify the range of all non-empty cells, 
(2) loop through that range column-by-column, 
(3) loop through each column cell-by-cell

```
Sub LoopThruUsedRangeColByCol()
    Dim rngCol, rngAll, cell As Range, cnt As Long
    Set rngAll = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    'MsgBox R.Address(0, 0), , "All data"
    cnt = 0
    For Each rngCol In rngAll.Columns
        rngCol.Select
        For Each cell In Selection
            cnt = cnt + 1
            Debug.Print (cell.Address)
            Debug.Print (cell.row)
            Debug.Print (cell.Column)
            If cnt > 3 Then End
        Next cell
    Next rngCol
End Sub
```

#### Notes:

(1) `cnt` added only so the output does not overwhelm. Remove `If cnt > 3 Then End` after demo.

(2) you need to open the "immediate window" to see the debug.print output. 
To do this: Menubar => View menu => Immediate Window